# End to end protocol?

Tags: tcp, ip

I read from [here](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy556/material/tutorials/cs556-3rd-tutorial.pdf) that sockets are uniquely identified by an end-to-end protocol. What does "end-to-end" mean, generally, in networks?

Comment: Could that PDF have been a book from the "TCP/IP sockets in X: Practical Guide for Programmers" (X being a programming language)? Or something else?

Comment: No its from http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy556/material/tutorials/cs556-3rd-tutorial.pdf @Gerben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An end-to-end protocol is responsible for delivering messages to one or multiple network endpoints.

Referring to the [ISO/OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), end-to-end protocols work on the Transport Layer (Layer 4), i.e. UDP or TCP.

IMHO, the [end-to-end principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle) basically is about the communication between two or more processes in the network.